# proxy and php scripts

Tags: proxy

It is probably a simple question but I dont know how to solve my problem.

There is a proxy on the network I am using. I execute php scripts on command line (composer.phar not to same the name). The script, using curl obviously, try to download file from http urls. I cannot download because of the proxy.

So my question is this one :
 where should I configure proxy settings to use a tool like composer.phar ?

Maybe the command line is not the problem and I would have the same problem if I were using curl in an application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add a HTTP_PROXY system environment variable to make it work